# How do I view a log file generated by screen (screenlog.0)

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, terminal, gnu-screen

So I just found out I can create log files of everything I do in screen (C-a H). Sounds like a nice way to keep track of potential goofs in a particular screen session. However, when I went to try it out the logfile is reported as being a binary file (and can't be viewed like a regular text as such). So am I missing something? A quick man page looksee and searching Google (and SO) turns up nothing about this.

**So my question is: How do I generate plain text log files in screen?**

Assuming the answer is "What a noob... how about you try making them? RTFM." my question becomes: How do I use less to view screen logfiles I've created (since `less screenlog.0` does not work on a binary file)?

---

**EDIT:** So `cat` works fine but `less` complains that the file is binary... why?

---

**SOLUTION:** as jcomeau_ictx helpfully pointed out, you can view these logfiles fine with `cat` or `more` but with `less` you must add the -r flag `less -r screenlog.0`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just found a screenlog.0 on the net; it *is* plain text, with some escape sequences. Just 'cat' the file, you should be able to view it just fine.

[after more checking]
Control-A H is what generates the screenlog on my system. And though 'cat' works, you'll miss a lot of data. Use 'more' instead of 'less' to interpolate the escape codes.

Comment: OK, this is strange because while I can indeed use `cat screenlog.0` and it works fine, `less screenlog.0` complains about a binary file and outputs the usual binary garble. Why?

Comment: 'less' in its default state treats escape sequences as binary data, and 'more' in its default state does not. there are switches that might influence this behavior, but if so I've forgotten them. the manpage for 'less' should suggest some things to try.

Comment: the escape sequences, in case you're unfamiliar with them, are a way to store cursor positioning, font color and style, and other such data. it dates back to the DEC VT-52 screen monitors, probably before.

Comment: Wow! I use less all the time and never knew that. The more you learn... thanks!

Comment: Looks like `less -r screenlog.0` will do it. `-r` is `--raw-control-chars`

Answer (score 2):

I found neither less nor more nor cat to be an ideal solution for viewing screenlog files. All "replay" some of the control character so that e.g. screen deletions as produced by "clear" (don't remember the corresponding control character) are beeing shown, hiding what has been cleared.

What i know works great is: use "view" or "vi", it just shows the control character in escaped notation. Probably any other text editor works, too (not tested).

Comment: Yes, "more" is not ideal, but the one upside is that it can interpret/produce the colors from the log (if present), which can make it easier to visualize errors.

Answer (score 2):

-L logs to file, 
tail -f 'logfilename' to monitor this file