# Permission denied when mounting volume to Fluentd in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, permission-denied, fluentd, mounted-volumes

The following is the DaemonSet for fluentd setup

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: logging
  labels:
    app: fluentd
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: fluentd
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: fluentd
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: fluentd
        image: fluent/fluentd:v1.15-1

        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 512Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: fluentd-config
          mountPath: /fluentd/etc
          readOnly: true
        - name: varlogpods
          mountPath: /home/fluent/log/pods
          readOnly: true

      volumes:
      - name: fluentd-config
        configMap:
          name: fluentd-configmap
      - name: varlogpods
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log/pods
```

The configmap configuration used,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: fluentd-configmap
  namespace: logging
  labels:
    app: fluentd
data:
  fluent.conf: |
    <source>
      @type tail
      path /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi*/fastapi/*.log
      pos_file /home/fluent/var/log/fluentd-docker.pos
      tag fastapi
      read_from_head true
      <parse>
          @type none
      </parse>
    </source>
    <match fastapi>
        @type stdout
    </match>
```

The default user in the kubernetes pod "fluent".The volume mounts files with user root.When fluentd start to tail the file, permission denied.How to fix the problem?

The the following when check the logs of the fluentd pod,

```
2022-09-03 07:36:15 +0000 [info]: parsing config file is succeeded path="/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf"
2022-09-03 07:36:15 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluentd' version '1.15.2'
2022-09-03 07:36:15 +0000 [info]: using configuration file: <ROOT>
  <source>
    @type tail
    path "/home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi*/fastapi/*.log"
    pos_file "/home/fluent/var/log/fluentd-docker.pos"
    tag "fastapi"
    read_from_head true
    <parse>
      @type "none"
      unmatched_lines
    </parse>
  </source>
  <match fastapi>
    @type stdout
  </match>
</ROOT>
2022-09-03 07:36:15 +0000 [info]: starting fluentd-1.15.2 pid=9 ruby="3.1.2"
2022-09-03 07:36:15 +0000 [info]: spawn command to main:  cmdline=["/usr/bin/ruby", "-Eascii-8bit:ascii-8bit", "/usr/bin/fluentd", "--config", "/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf", "--plugin", "/fluentd/plugins", "--under-supervisor"]
2022-09-03 07:36:16 +0000 [info]: adding match pattern="fastapi" type="stdout"
2022-09-03 07:36:16 +0000 [info]: adding source type="tail"
2022-09-03 07:36:16 +0000 [info]: #0 starting fluentd worker pid=18 ppid=9 worker=0
2022-09-03 07:36:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-j65mb_a0e86e32-8999-49ff-abe5-fba65fb7af66/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:36:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-mppdl_2af9ab32-0f2e-4777-8394-7452e50068ea/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:36:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-j65mb_a0e86e32-8999-49ff-abe5-fba65fb7af66/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:36:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-mppdl_2af9ab32-0f2e-4777-8394-7452e50068ea/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:36:16 +0000 [info]: #0 fluentd worker is now running worker=0
2022-09-03 07:37:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-j65mb_a0e86e32-8999-49ff-abe5-fba65fb7af66/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:37:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-mppdl_2af9ab32-0f2e-4777-8394-7452e50068ea/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:38:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-j65mb_a0e86e32-8999-49ff-abe5-fba65fb7af66/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:38:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-mppdl_2af9ab32-0f2e-4777-8394-7452e50068ea/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:39:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-j65mb_a0e86e32-8999-49ff-abe5-fba65fb7af66/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:39:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-mppdl_2af9ab32-0f2e-4777-8394-7452e50068ea/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:40:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-j65mb_a0e86e32-8999-49ff-abe5-fba65fb7af66/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:40:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-mppdl_2af9ab32-0f2e-4777-8394-7452e50068ea/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:41:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-j65mb_a0e86e32-8999-49ff-abe5-fba65fb7af66/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:41:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-mppdl_2af9ab32-0f2e-4777-8394-7452e50068ea/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:42:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-j65mb_a0e86e32-8999-49ff-abe5-fba65fb7af66/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:42:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-mppdl_2af9ab32-0f2e-4777-8394-7452e50068ea/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:43:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-j65mb_a0e86e32-8999-49ff-abe5-fba65fb7af66/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:43:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-mppdl_2af9ab32-0f2e-4777-8394-7452e50068ea/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:44:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-j65mb_a0e86e32-8999-49ff-abe5-fba65fb7af66/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:44:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-mppdl_2af9ab32-0f2e-4777-8394-7452e50068ea/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:45:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-j65mb_a0e86e32-8999-49ff-abe5-fba65fb7af66/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:45:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-mppdl_2af9ab32-0f2e-4777-8394-7452e50068ea/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:46:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-j65mb_a0e86e32-8999-49ff-abe5-fba65fb7af66/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:46:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-mppdl_2af9ab32-0f2e-4777-8394-7452e50068ea/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:47:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-j65mb_a0e86e32-8999-49ff-abe5-fba65fb7af66/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:47:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-mppdl_2af9ab32-0f2e-4777-8394-7452e50068ea/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:48:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-j65mb_a0e86e32-8999-49ff-abe5-fba65fb7af66/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:48:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-mppdl_2af9ab32-0f2e-4777-8394-7452e50068ea/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:49:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-j65mb_a0e86e32-8999-49ff-abe5-fba65fb7af66/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:49:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-mppdl_2af9ab32-0f2e-4777-8394-7452e50068ea/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:50:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-j65mb_a0e86e32-8999-49ff-abe5-fba65fb7af66/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:50:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-mppdl_2af9ab32-0f2e-4777-8394-7452e50068ea/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:51:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-j65mb_a0e86e32-8999-49ff-abe5-fba65fb7af66/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:51:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-mppdl_2af9ab32-0f2e-4777-8394-7452e50068ea/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:52:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-j65mb_a0e86e32-8999-49ff-abe5-fba65fb7af66/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
2022-09-03 07:52:16 +0000 [warn]: #0 /home/fluent/log/pods/default_fastapi-9bbf7747c-mppdl_2af9ab32-0f2e-4777-8394-7452e50068ea/fastapi/0.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
```

The following details when 'exec' inside the fluentd pod

```
~/log/pods/logging_fluentd-prv5g_a8b84184-bfd6-4aee-ac13-f34302ee501e/fluentd $ whoami
fluent
~/log/pods/logging_fluentd-prv5g_a8b84184-bfd6-4aee-ac13-f34302ee501e/fluentd $ cat /home/fluent/log/pods/logging_fluentd-prv5g_a8b84184-bf
d6-4aee-ac13-f34302ee501e/fluentd/0.log
cat: can't open '/home/fluent/log/pods/logging_fluentd-prv5g_a8b84184-bfd6-4aee-ac13-f34302ee501e/fluentd/0.log': Permission denied
~/log/pods/logging_fluentd-prv5g_a8b84184-bfd6-4aee-ac13-f34302ee501e/fluentd $ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r-----    1 root     root          4045 Sep  3 07:38 0.log
~/log/pods/logging_fluentd-prv5g_a8b84184-bfd6-4aee-ac13-f34302ee501e/fluentd $
```

Comment: Copy paste the error do not post images of the error

Comment: Also did you try following this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43558042/permission-issue-when-reading-container-logs-with-fluentd-in-kubernetes

Comment: Can you share the config map manifest as well ? I am trying to replicate the scenario

Comment: @sidharthvijayakumar The configmap manifest added

Comment: first thing, the mount is read only. what if you do not set readonly=true

Comment: Your pod is up and running but getting error while you try to hit a command inside the pod. Am I right ?

Comment: at the end of the volumes section add securityContext:
        fsGroup: 82

Comment: @sidharthvijayakumar I am not getting any error inside the pod. The problem is inside the pod default user is 'fluent' which is used in the fluentd official docker image. When I mount the volume is adding the logs that are owned by the root user. So, when the user 'fluent' tried to read the file,permission got denied.

Comment: @jmvcollaborator It doesn't work

Comment: ok, in the image can you grant permissions to the folder? fluent/fluentd:v1.15-1

Comment: @jmvcollaborator add readonly=true because the files from the mounted volume do not need any permission other than read.

Comment: why cat: can't open '/home/fluent/log/pods/logging_fluentd-prv5g_a8b84184-bfd6-4aee-ac13-f34302ee501e/fluentd/0.log': Permission denied

Comment: @jmvcollaborator I tried creating a new fluentd image with the root user. It works fine. I require to use the official fluentd image

Comment: USER root on the docker file ?

Comment: @jmvcollaborator permission denied because the default user in the pod is named 'fluent'.The files mounted are owned by the root user. The user 'fluent' doesn't have permission to read files owned by the root user.

Comment: @jmvcollaborator Yes I created the image with USER root on the docker file. It worked fine.

Comment: then i was correct saying permissions, happy you fixed it

Comment: @sidharthvijayakumar what you have done? Created new image with root USER

Comment: no I used secuirity context but I cannot cat that file but it opens in vi

Comment: It opened for me as well when used vi. But file is empty

Comment: yes its not a file or directory as per the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420386/how-do-i-view-a-log-file-generated-by-screen-screenlog-0

Comment: @sidharthvijayakumar It is a file. I tried to cat the file in the host path and has data in the file

Comment: this is when u use unofficial docker image ?

Comment: no, official docker image

Comment: How did u fix this? by using root in docker file?

Comment: tried with the fluentd docker image that i created with root user permission. It works fine. https://hub.docker.com/layers/arjun2038/fluentdsuperuser/latest/images/sha256-4ee6bca20d3c3e8c6907a2fc5ce22c147710d5b885498b5540e4484b604c8997?context=repo

Comment: Yes Modified docker image with root user permission

Comment: If this works for u then cool but on a security level this is a bad practice.

Comment: Do you have any idea to fix this issue other than modifying the image?

Comment: But why do you want to view the file by using exec ? Maybe create a user with less permission than root and then use that user.